# Labels on pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe which I plot as a matrix:

```
symbol      abc    def   xyz
symbol
abc         1     0.2    0.5
def         0.2     1    0.3
xyz         0.5   0.3      1
```

I plot it as follows:

```
plt.pcolormesh(df.values)
```

Is there a way to plot the values of each cell inside the cell? In other words I don't want a legend on the side, I want to have the value of each pair plotted inside the relevant cells of the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to create a `plt.text` object for each cell on the `pcolormesh`. This loop should do what you want. There may be a vectorised way to do this, but at least this works.

```
for ii,i in enumerate(df.index):
    for jj,j in enumerate(df.keys()):
        plt.text(ii+0.5,jj+0.5,df[i][j])
```

Here it is in a full script:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.viridis()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'abc':{'abc':1.0,'def':0.2,'xyz':0.5},
    'def':{'abc':0.2,'def':1.0,'xyz':0.3},
    'xyz':{'abc':0.5,'def':0.3,'xyz':1.0}})

plt.pcolormesh(df.values)

for ii,i in enumerate(df.index):
    for jj,j in enumerate(df.keys()):
        plt.text(ii+0.5,jj+0.5,df[i][j],
                ha='center',va='center',
                size=20,color='w')

plt.show()
```

[image]